# Tmux breaks "who am i" (who -m)

Tags: centos, tmux

Within tmux when I type "who am i" (more formally, `who -m`) I get a blank response.

Obviously this would be a minor niggle -- except that our vendor's code uses it to establish user ID, and won't run without it. So I can't use my normal development tools within tmux.

I'm on Centos 6.5 and Centos 7.  This is reproducible on both.

I know that with screen this is a known issue caused by screen not starting shells in login mode?  But tmux *does* start shells in login mode; I can confirm that, because I can see that it's running my .profile again.

Comment: How do you start `tmux`? `who` reads from a file that is modified by the  `login` program, so whether or not your shell is a login shell may be irrelevant.

Comment: I'm just typing 'tmux' ...

Comment: Just to add to this: `who /var/log/wtmp` shows all the users. `who /var/log/utmp` (which is apparently the default) shows nothing. But `who -m /var/log/wtmp` shows nothing...

Comment: BTW if anyone else ever has this exact problem -- wrap `who` with a shell script that outputs fake details... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a genuine bug, since it was specifically mentioned in the changelogs for tmux 2.0 -- which fixes it.